# How to programatically get the character encoding a font supports?

Tags: c#, fonts

Is there a way, using C#, to get the character encoding a Font supports?

Comment: Fonts and encodings are entirely orthogonal; a single font can be used by multiple encodings, a single encoding can use multiple fonts. There is no one-to-one relationship between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

In the .Net world, there are not code pages: everything is done in Unicode.

A font is a collection of glyphs (a graphic representation of a character) mapped onto a subset of Unicode codepoints (32-bit integers).

CLR strings are UTF-16 encoded lists of System.Char (unsigned 16-bit integers). This means that certain Unicode codepoints (0x00000080 and higher) are represented in the string as a pair of 16-bit characters, computed according to UTF-16. Internally[1], the string is converted from UTF-16 to UTF-32 and the now-32-bit characters are used to look up the appropriate glyph.

[1]Logically, anyway. I've got no idea what the actual implementation details are.

Comment: There is not a 1:1 mapping of character:glyph, especially not in unicode. Think of ligatures... (1 glpyh representing a certain set+order of 2 or three characters, such as *ffi*).

Comment: Typographically, to quote Wikipedia, "*In writing and typography, a ligature occurs where two or more *graphemes* are joined as a single *glyph*.*" (a grapheme being a fundamental unit of a written lanuage -- a letter for us westerners.) In a ligature, the shape of the individual letterforms is dependent on context. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature for more info. But I'd argue that for the purposes of this question, the difference between character and glyph is rather pedantic.